# Error showing when starting Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

```
2014-10-18 08:33:43.531:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:NO JSP Support for /solr, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Null identity service, trying login service: null
Finding identity service: null
```

I have been getting the following errors when running solr with Rails. I installed sunspot_rails via bundler:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'sunspot_solr', '2.1.1'
end
gem 'sunspot_rails', '2.1.1'
```

I am able to access the `localhost:8982' but see the following on top of the page:

[image]
[image]

Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `Gemfile` :-

```
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_solr' # optional pre-packaged Solr distribution for use in development
gem 'progress_bar'
```

needless to say...you need to install first `install java jdk` steps mentioned [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux)..*sorry i cannot paste the steps here as referring to it will be more good*

..HOPE IT HELPS...